# Taglist: Failed to generate tags for macvim

Tags: vim

Whenever I am trying to open a file in my Rails project using **macVim**. I am getting an error

```
Taglist: Failed to generate tags for .......
```

But it works perfectly in terminal vim. Why is this happening? I am a beginner and just installed everything using this [dotvim](https://github.com/astrails/dotvim) repo.

I installed ctags using these commands that I got from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/1570678):

```
$ ctags -R --exclude=.git --exclude=log *
ctags: illegal option -- R
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...

#you need to get new ctags, i recommend homebrew but anything will work
$ brew install ctags

#alias ctags if you used homebrew
$ alias ctags="`brew --prefix`/bin/ctags"

#try again!
ctags -R --exclude=.git --exclude=log *
```

`which ctags` on terminal returning, same if I do from vim or gvim using `!` (bang):

```
 /usr/bin/ctags
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the `PATH` order to make `/usr/local/bin/ctags` ahead of of `/usr/bin/ctags`. The way I prefer to achieve this is by add `/usr/local/bin` to the beginning of `/etc/paths`:

```
# for homebrew
/usr/local/bin

# original order
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
#/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just set a variable like

```
let g:Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/local/bin/ctags'  " Proper ctags location
```

in your .vimrc file.